# Pass Variable to Self-Written Module on Import?

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, python-module

I want to import a handful of settings to my current script, held an external module, called settings.py.

Currently, I change the 'animal' variable by hand before importing.

**settings.py**:

```
animal='Unicorn' #I want to get rid of this line, and pass the variable during the import.

if animal=='Unicorn':
        fur_color='sparkles'
        number_of_legs=4

if animal=='Centipede':
    fur_color='black'
    number_of_legs=100

if animal =='Cat':
    fur_color='brown'
    number_of_legs=4
```

I run:

```
from settings import fur_color, number_of_legs
```

and have the information needed.

However, I need to loop through the 3 cases now. I can't do this, as in  my current setup, I have to manually change the 'animal' variable before importing.

How can I pass animal in to the settings, so that I can write something like:

```
for animal in animals:
    from settings import *
    print('A' + animal + ' has ' + str(number_of_legs) + ' and is ' + fur_color)
```

Desired output would be:

```
A Unicorn has 4 legs and is sparkles
A Centipede has 100 legs and is black
A Cat has 4 legs and is brown.
```

The "import" inside the loop does NOT update the settings, not does using imp.reload(settings). I am at a loss for what to do here. Obviously, the real use case is more complex. I really hope I haven't shot myself in the foot by storing the case by case variables in this manner!!

Comment: Modules are only imported once even if there are multiple `import` statements to the same module. Any reason why you don't want to turn this into a `settings.get_animal('unicorn')`?

Comment: @Andreas Deak, that is probably what I've been looking for! Could you elaborate in an answer? How would I build something like "get_animal" into the existing settings.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are imported only once, even if there are subsequent imports of the same module. This means that I don't expect there to be an easy way to work with your current setup.

I suggest defining a function in `settings` that will generate the configuration you want based on its string input:

```
def get_animal(kind):
    if kind == 'Unicorn':
        fur_color = 'sparkles'
        number_of_legs = 4
    elif kind == 'Centipede':
        fur_color = 'black'
        number_of_legs = 100
    elif kind == 'Cat':
        fur_color = 'brown'
        number_of_legs = 4
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid animal {kind}!')
    #return dict(fur_color=fur_color, number_of_legs=number_of_legs)
    # or
    return fur_color, number_of_legs
```

Then you can get the corresponding dict as

```
from settings import get_animal
for animal in animals:
    animal_dict = get_animal(animal)
    # animal_dict['fur_color'] etc. can be accessed
    print('A {animal} has {number_of_legs} legs and is {fur_color}'.format(
         animal=animal, **animal_dict))
```

Of course if your use case is something for which a dict is less appropriate you can define the function with the tuple return value, and then unpack that:

```
from settings import get_animal
for animal in animals:
    fur_color,number_of_legs = get_animal(animal)
    # do complicated stuff here
```

Comment: Could you suggest a more elegant way to unpack the 12 vairables I'm defining in there? It's a very long and ugly one-liner: `base_path, data_columns, general_data_columns, out_date_format, precip_columns, precip_gage_change, primary_temp_column, temp_columns, timezone, wind_col, wind_dir_columns=settings.get_settings(Glacier, Station)`. I think this is the dictionary option you suggested?

Comment: @EHB Well you can always bind that tuple to temporary name and access each item by indexing, like `base_path = settings_tuple[0]; data_columns = settings_tuple[1]` etc. But the reason I thought of a dict in the first place is that I suspected that you have a lot of these variables. You can either accept your fate and use this long unpacking (possibly with some explicit line continuations using `\` at the end of the line), or keep them all in a dict and access the items by name (preferably with a short-named dict and short-named keys...). I'm not sure if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

This is really best done by calling a function in the external module. That could be done like this:

settings.py:

```
def animal_info(animal):
    if animal=='Unicorn':
        fur_color='sparkles'
        number_of_legs=4
    elif animal=='Centipede':
        fur_color='black'
        number_of_legs=100
    elif animal =='Cat':
        fur_color='brown'
        number_of_legs=4
    return fur_color, number_of_legs
```

Then, in your main module or at the interactive prompt, you can just use this:

```
import settings
for animal in animals:
    fur_color, number_of_legs = settings.animal_info(animal)
    print('A' + animal + ' has ' + str(number_of_legs) + ' and is ' + fur_color)
```

If you’re working with a larger table of data than this, then you may want to consider using a `pandas` dataframe. Just store your data in a comma-separated or tab-separated text file, then read it in with `df = pandas.read_csv(....)`, set an index based on your lookup column(s), then access data like `df.loc[animal, “number of legs”]`.

Comment: The blib about pandas is just unnecessary complicating things. The are many serialisation modules in standard library that'll fit better the use case, including a perfectly usable csv module. In any case, the reason people use a settings.py file is so that the setting files can contain logic, which csv/pandas can't really solve anyway.

Comment: The part about pandas was added in response to EHB's comment on the accepted answer, where they thought it was inelegant to unpack a long list of variable names, and indicated that they had a two-element index. By extension, it would be inelegant to generate all this data from a .py file. That much data should probably be in a text file, and then pandas is an easy way to access it. Python's csv.DictReader could do this, but you'd need to follow up with extra code to convert the rows into a dict of dicts for efficient searching. Easier to just use pandas, which is made for exactly that.

Comment: @MathiasFripp: so install pandas, which has thousands of lines of code that you'll never use, and adds dependencies that you're not interested in, including numpy which may need a C compiler to install and dependencies on system libraries. All that so you can save one line of dictionary comprehension (`{(row["animal"], row["number of legs"]): row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile)}`)? You've got a weird way of defining "easier".